# How to use cypress parallel feature without record?

Tags: cypress, circleci

I have registered for basic cypress plan, the one that's free. Now after giving the project id and passing --parallel flag, the tests run in parallel successfully.

The command I used

```
npx cypress run --headless --browser electron --record --key=<key> --parallel
```

This started to work as expected. I used 4 machines on circleCI to work with parallel feature. However since I have a large number of tests, I ran out of space for storing test results after few builds. Soon got the email to upgrade the cypress package. But the upgraded package also has a limit of storing 10k test results only which I am afraid will not last more than a week. https://www.cypress.io/pricing/

My question is, is there any way I can use this parallel feature and do not record the test results. Just make use of the parallel feature with CircleCI. TIA

Answer (score 1):

One option can be to go for [Sorry-Cypress](https://sorry-cypress.dev/) which is an open-source alternative for Cypress Dashboard.

Inside the documentation I found this [basic setup](https://docs.sorry-cypress.dev/configuration/in-memory), which talks about test parallelisation without the overhead of maintaining and paying for the infrastructure required to keep and browse tests results.

Comment: Sorry-Cypress seems to be interesting and saving bucks. But dashboard not UI friendly :(